# Interface-Class-Object,Casting,Exception

Tags: java, object, interface, casting

I  saw  this  code:

```
interface I{}    

class A implements I{}

class B extends A{}

class C  extends B{}

class ABC
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      A a=new A();
      B b=new B();              
      a=(B)(I)b;  //Line 1
      b=(B)(I)a;  //Line 2
      a=(I)b;     //Line 3
      I i=(C)a;  //Line 4
    }
}
```

Trying to find out

1. which  way  to  have  a  safe  casting i.e  without  compile  time  or  run  time  error
2. In  what  circumstances  casting  will  show  compile  time  error
3. In  what  circumstances  casting  will  show  run  time  exception

Can  any  one  explain  me  these  3  concepts?

Comment: For line three, it's not the *cast* that causes the compile-time failure - it's an attempt to assign a value of compile-time type `I` to a variable of type `A`...

Comment: On line 2, you've got an object that's NOT a `B`, and you're trying to assign it to a variable of type `B`.  Why would this be OK at run time?

Comment: Because  we  have  casted  it  to  B @david

Comment: I don't think you know what casting is.  It's not a way of converting an object from one class to another.  It doesn't change the underlying object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java, an interface as similar to a class is a type. In your example and object of class A is oftype A and is oftype I. An object of class B is oftype B, oftype(subtype) A and oftype I. An object of class C is oftype C, oftype(subtype) B, oftype(subtype) A and oftype I. As noticed, the objects are oftypes of 2 types (te two types have no link to each other i.e. A and I are independently types) and subtypes of their respective super classes.

As per Leskov's substitution principal, you can sunstiture a subtype (sub-class) in place of a supertype(super-class). To illustrate look at the code fragment below:

public class InheritanceTest {

```
public interface I{}
public class A implements I{}
public class B extends A{}
public class C extends B{}
public class D implements I{}
public class E{}

public void method(){

    A a=new A();
    B b=new B();
    C c=new C();

    D d=new D();

    I i=null;

    i=a;i=b;i=c;

    a=b;
    b=c;
    a=c;

    a=(A)i;//a=i does not work, A and I are two different types

    i=d;
    a=(A)i;//ClassCastException at runtime, D is not an A

    E e=new E();
    //a=(A)e; - this generates a compile time error

}//method closing
```

}//class closing

The cast is necessary because, as per the code, all As are Is but all Is are not As i.e. I could have a class D which implemented I but is completely unconnected to the A inheritance hierarchy. In general, then when you have to convert between two unconnected types, you need to cast.

NOTE: I have edited the code to include another class D
NOTE: I have edited the code to include another class E

Comment: Last  but  2  lines  do  you mean  a=(D)i? @Ironlca

Comment: @Gpar, I have edited the code slightly, what I wanted to highlight is that an object of type D, though of oftype I is not-oftype A (as A and I are two independent types). At compile time this line will not generate any error at run-time it will.

Comment: I  may  be  bit  stupid  to  ask  this  sorry,  Why  cant  compiler  see  i=d  and  d  cant  be  of  type  A  and  then  show  compile  time  error  rather  than  run  time  exception?  As  a=(A)d;  is  a  compile  time  error  @Ironluca

Comment: @Gpar, it is a natural question. First, objects of class A are oftype I. Second, Java being a strongly typed language, checks the type assignments of objects, now, this type checking operates on compile time information that is available, for example variable(symbol) i is oftype I, variable a is oftype A, object of A is also oftype I is available, so a cast is permitted, the compiler typically cannot determine what is actually assigned to i, that is a run-time matter, so it does not generate any error on a=(A)i ... cont.

Comment: The last line (commented), it is known at compile time that a and e are not of same type, so a compile time error is generated, run-time information is not necessary in this case to figure out that there is an error. That is also the reason why a=i assignment does not work, they are of two different type and a cast is necessary. So, whichever error is possible to be determined with compile time information is highlighted by compiler and for which run-time information is needed, the compiler does not generate errors

Comment: Thanks fro your time and patience. @Ironluca